# Export Import Web Part not working - This query has returned no items. To configure the query for this web part open the tool pane

Tags: .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I drag a content query web part to my page and then it shows three pages from within my site. I export it to a file and save it.

Then I change the following in my saved web part file:-

```
<property name="CommonViewFields" type="string" />
```

To

```
<property name="CommonViewFields" type="string" >EditorRemarks</property>
```

and

```
<property name="DataFields" type="string" />
```

To

```
<property name="DataFields" type="string" >EditorRemarks</property>
```

And then, when I delete the original web part and add the imported web part above. I get the following error :-

This query has returned no items. To configure the query for this Web Part, open the tool pane.

I have the "EditorRemarks" column in my content type.

I am totally new to sharepoint. Please tell me how can I resolve this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of [CommonViewFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.commonviewfields%28v=office.12%29.aspx) is `Internal Name,Type`. If you have multiple fields, they need to be separated with semicolons. Also, you should not need to change the DataFields property.

For more information on CommonViewFields, see step 17 of [Customizing the Content Query Web Part and Custom Item Styles](http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/articles/CustomItemStyle.aspx).